# PoetryException failed to install gssapi-1.8.2.tar.gz

Tags: python, linux, arcgis, python-poetry

I need to use ArcGIS API, so I've created a poetry environment and I've tried to install the API: `poetry add arcgis`.
Unfortunately I see the error message below:

```
 • Installing gssapi (1.8.2): Failed

  CalledProcessError

  Command '['/home/max/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/arcgis-api-UPBhVADH-py3.8/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '--use-pep517', '--disable-pip-version-check', '--prefix', '/home/max/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/arcgis-api-UPBhVADH-py3.8', '--no-deps', '/home/max/.cache/pypoetry/artifacts/64/da/a9/a06afe5c1d5ef8f2f266a3d030f065759a2632a554b16410139032456d/gssapi-1.8.2.tar.gz']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

  at /usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py:516 in run
       512│             # We don't call process.wait() as .__exit__ does that for us.
       513│             raise
       514│         retcode = process.poll()
       515│         if check and retcode:
    →  516│             raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
       517│                                      output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
       518│     return CompletedProcess(process.args, retcode, stdout, stderr)
       519│ 
       520│ 

The following error occurred when trying to handle this error:


  EnvCommandError

  Command ['/home/max/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/arcgis-api-UPBhVADH-py3.8/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '--use-pep517', '--disable-pip-version-check', '--prefix', '/home/max/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/arcgis-api-UPBhVADH-py3.8', '--no-deps', '/home/max/.cache/pypoetry/artifacts/64/da/a9/a06afe5c1d5ef8f2f266a3d030f065759a2632a554b16410139032456d/gssapi-1.8.2.tar.gz'] errored with the following return code 1, and output: 
  Processing /home/max/.cache/pypoetry/artifacts/64/da/a9/a06afe5c1d5ef8f2f266a3d030f065759a2632a554b16410139032456d/gssapi-1.8.2.tar.gz
    Installing build dependencies: started
    Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
    Getting requirements to build wheel: started
    Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'error'
    error: subprocess-exited-with-error
    
    × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
    │ exit code: 1
    ╰─> [21 lines of output]
        /bin/sh: 1: krb5-config: not found
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "/home/max/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/arcgis-api-UPBhVADH-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
            main()
          File "/home/max/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/arcgis-api-UPBhVADH-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 345, in main
            json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
          File "/home/max/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/arcgis-api-UPBhVADH-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 130, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
            return hook(config_settings)
          File "/tmp/pip-build-env-gh_kkuy0/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 338, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
            return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
          File "/tmp/pip-build-env-gh_kkuy0/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 320, in _get_build_requires
            self.run_setup()
          File "/tmp/pip-build-env-gh_kkuy0/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 335, in run_setup
            exec(code, locals())
          File "<string>", line 109, in <module>
          File "<string>", line 22, in get_output
          File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 415, in check_output
            return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
          File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 516, in run
            raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
        subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'krb5-config --libs gssapi' returned non-zero exit status 127.
        [end of output]
    
    note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  

  at ~/.local/share/pypoetry/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/utils/env.py:1476 in _run
      1472│                 output = subprocess.check_output(
      1473│                     command, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, env=env, **kwargs
      1474│                 )
      1475│         except CalledProcessError as e:
    → 1476│             raise EnvCommandError(e, input=input_)
      1477│ 
      1478│         return decode(output)
      1479│ 
      1480│     def execute(self, bin: str, *args: str, **kwargs: Any) -> int:

The following error occurred when trying to handle this error:


  PoetryException

  Failed to install /home/max/.cache/pypoetry/artifacts/64/da/a9/a06afe5c1d5ef8f2f266a3d030f065759a2632a554b16410139032456d/gssapi-1.8.2.tar.gz

  at ~/.local/share/pypoetry/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/utils/pip.py:51 in pip_install
       47│ 
       48│     try:
       49│         return environment.run_pip(*args)
       50│     except EnvCommandError as e:
    →  51│         raise PoetryException(f"Failed to install {path.as_posix()}") from e
       52│
```

And the package isn't installed.

Here the `pyproject.toml`:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "arcgis-api"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = []
readme = "README.md"
packages = [{include = "arcgis_api"}]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = ">=3.8,<3.10"


[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 with Poetry 1.2.1 and I can't use Conda for this project.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and made sure these libraries were installed:

**Ubuntu**

```
sudo apt-get install libkrb5-dev gcc python3-dev
```

**Arch**

```
sudo pacman -S krb5 e2fsprogs
```

I also added the below libraries in the dependencies section of the .toml file:

```
pywinrm = "^0.4.3"
arcgis = "^2.0.0"
```

*Reasons: gssapi needs pywinrm and libkrb5-dev installed to work and arcgis needs gssapi to work